# Achieve same results with ToString() as with String.Format

Tags: c#, formatting

Can't figure out how to implement this task:

I need to format a decimal like this

```
 var formatted = String.Format("{0:G}%", numberOfDecimalType);
```

So, the result should be number formatted number with trailing % sign.
The problem is that I need to get this result using `.ToString()` method.
I've tried `numberOfDecimalType.ToString("G%")` and different other variants but it didn't help

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to use `.ToString()` if you already know that `String.Format(...)` returns what you want?

Comment: It's the requirement of low-level component. I can only send a format mask and it subsequently calls .ToString(formatMask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add literal characters by using a [*custom numeric format string*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var formatted = numberOfDecimalType.ToString(@"#,##0.##\%");
```

The backslash ensures that `%` is treated as a literal character rather than a special formatting instruction.

Note, though, that this is not an *exact* replacement of `G`, i.e., you might need to adjust the number of `#`s to accommodate for the required number of decimal places.

Comment: Not sure it will return only significant decimal places

Comment: Result is not correct  var number = 0.0076m;
`var formatted = String.Format("{0:G}%", number); //0.0076%
var otherformatted= number.ToString(@"#,###0.##\%"); //0.01%`

Comment: @KokaChernov: That's what I meant by "adjusting the number of `#`s, e.g. `#,##0.#########`, if you (potentially) need a lot of decimal places. I don't think there is an *exact* equivalent to `G` as a custom format string.

Comment: Then I guess I need to count significant decimal places on the fly? It it possible?

Comment: @KokaChernov: I don't think so. Can you provide an upper bound on the number of significant decimal places?

Comment: sure - 6 is maximum, but trailing zeros should be removed

Comment: @KokaChernov: That should work, `#` won't display trailing zeros (as opposed to `0`, which would).

Comment: Thx for your help mister Heinzi!

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to append the "%" to the end using a single `ToString` call; you'll need to format the decimal using `ToString` and then append the percent sign separately:

```
var formatted = numberOfDecimalType.ToString("G") + "%";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply append the percent, couldn't you?

```
formatted = numberOfDecimalType.ToString("G") + "%";
```

Comment: @KokaChernov: So you can only provide the string for `ToString`? Or can you also provide a different number? For example: `(0.01m * numberOfDecimalType).ToString("P");`

Comment: I Can only send a format string, that would be used like .ToString(FormatString)